# sleeping during an execlp call to avoid output 'lag'? is it possible?

Tags: c, linux, shell, process

Currently i'm screwin around with a shell that i'm developing for Linux in C, and somebody recently pointed me towards execlp to execute separate programs from within my shell. The example i have implemented in the shell currently is very simple, execute the shell, run the 'date' command, and execlp launches 'date', which, simply enough, prints the date to the terminal. the problem in this case, is although the date program executes successfully and prints to the terminal, it prints right after the shell prompt. I'm guessing execlp returns the date just a hair too late, causing it to show up after the prompt prints. Is there a way to avoid the 'lag'? A sleep function seems like it would fit here, but I wouldn't know how to implement it around execlp like that.. Any ideas here??

Thanks!

Comment: If your "shell" is running the commands on "foreground", it should wait for the process to finish before doing anything else, including the prompt printing. https://linux.die.net/man/2/wait

Comment: The method I'm using currently takes advantage of fork and execlp. When a command is sent by the user, if it matches an existing command, the command executor is invoked which starts by forking itself, checking &/Or waiting for PID of 0, and then invoking execlp("date", "date", NULL). I was expecting it to execute date, print to stdout, and then return from the executor function back to main, which then re-enters the shell input loop.. So technically it is running in the foreground, I just don't know how to implement a sleep() function that waits till execlp's execution completes.

Comment: You seem not to appreciate the effect of `fork()`.  It creates a separate process that then runs independently from the parent.  This is exactly what you need if you're going to use `execlp()` or one of its brethren for your purpose (which you should), but it means that the child *does not* re-enter the shell input loop.  The parent does.  Moreover, the parent does not wait for the child except as you explicitly tell it to do.  Forking would otherwise be pretty pointless.

Comment: @ZeroAndOne You're saying your child process waits and then execlps? If so, that's your problem. It's the parent process that must wait for the child. The child should not wait on anything.

Comment: @JohnBollinger forking is useful even if the parent is waiting for the child, as the `exec` functions replace the process, but you still want to resume it at some point.

Comment: Sure, @EugeneSh., but the intended "otherwise" of "the parent does not wait for the child except as you explicitly tell it to do" is "the parent *always* waits for the child".  Granted, "pointless" might be a bit too strong a description of that, but not much.  After all, we also have `system()`.

Answer (score 1):

You `wait()` for your child process to return before issuing the prompt. The code below is an oversimplification of what needs to be done, but gives you the general gist:

```
   switch (pid = fork()) {
   case 0:   execlp("date", "date", (char *)NULL);
             exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   case -1:  perror("fork");
             break;
   default:  while ((r = waitpid(pid, &status, 0)) == (pid_t)-1) {
                if (errno != EINTR) {
                    perror("wait");
                    break;
                }
             }
   }
```